# Guideline 3.1.2 auto renewable promotion rejected?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I am trying to submit an app with auto-renewable subscriptions that are also promoted within the App Store. However, whenever I submit it for app review it always gets rejected for the following reason:

> We noticed that your app did not fully meet the terms and conditions
> for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section
> 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.
>
> When the user initiates an in-app purchase on the App Store, they are
> taken into your app to continue the transaction.
>
> However, information about the subscription must be displayed to the
> user prior to the purchase:
>
> • Title of publication or service
>
> • Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided
> during each subscription period)
> Price of subscription, and price per
> unit if appropriate
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to include the missing
> information prior to initiating any auto-renewing subscription
> purchases within your app.
>
> If you have no future plans on promoting this in-app purchase product,
> you can visit App Store Connect to delete the associated promotional
> image.
>
> ...

It seems that Apple requires the app to display info related to the subscription before the user initiates the purchase from the App Store. However, I don't know where to display this info. Do I have to override some method that tells me when the user is directed to my app from the App Store to buy the subscription? I tried to add all this missing information within the in-app purchase metadata like the description, but it still got rejected. Do I show this information in the landing page of the app? How do I satisfy this requirement?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question for Apple iTunes Support, not a question about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put in on the page where the users can purchase your premium subscription.

Here is an example of one of my apps:

[image: Example]

Also do not forget to add links to your Privacy Policy and your Terms of Service. If either one is missing, Apple will reject your app.